# Image of a measure zero set is zero

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Prove that if $\varphi:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ is a homeomorphism, then there is a set $Z\subset\Bbb R^n$
of measure zero $|Z|=0$ such that for each measurable set
$A$ the following implication is satisfied:
$$
A\subset\Bbb R^n\setminus Z, |A|=0 \implies |\varphi(A)|=0\, .
$$

My try: If I consider $\mu(E)=\phi(E)$ then $\mu $ is a measure. Now I think that I have to use Radon-Nikodym thm which states that $\lambda,\mu$ are $\sigma$-finite  and $\lambda<<\mu$ then there is a non-negative meas fn $h:X \to [0,\infty]$ s.t
$$\lambda(E)=\int_Ehd\mu, \text{ for all $E \in \mathfrak m$}.$$ But I am not getting a way to construct $\lambda$ and prove the problem. Any help/hint?